# Is this image of Picard using Data as a phone from an actual episode?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, episode-identification

Someone just sent me this image:

[image: Picard using a phone located in Data's chest, with the label "Smartphones - Picard uses Android"]

And, this one is viral on Facebook and Google+:

[image: same image with the label "I'm calling from my new Android smartphone - yes, it even includes unlimited Data"]

Are they from an actual TV episode, or are they Photoshopped images?

Comment: Dangit, you asked "from an actual episode", not "is it real"...  I wanted to say the answer was "yes _and_ no"!

Comment: I laughed so much when I saw the second one last night.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

[Real episode.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phantasms_%28Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation%29) This happened in the episode "Phantasms" (*Star Trek: The Next Generation*).

> In engineering, Data sees dream imagery while he's awake. He sees a 'mouth' on Geordi's neck, and the engineering tool he holds looks like the knife with which he cut the 'cellular-peptide cake'. He hears the telephone ringing again and Riker appears with a straw in his head, ordering Data to "answer it". **Data opens his own chest and picks up the telephone receiver.**

Comment: If I remember correctly, the phone is seen 2-3 times through the episode?

Comment: @Izkata Correct. This particular image comes from a scene where Picard and LaForge investigate Data's dream via the holodeck.

Comment: "It is a cellular peptide cake. With mint frosting." --Worf

Comment: I think this scene isn't entirely from Star Trek. The last part seems to be a sound effect copied in from another movie.